# How to format date from datepicker angular-material and Reactive Form using nameFormControl ? Angular 6

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

Could not format date. Whatever I tried to give me either this date "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z" or return my current date in good format. The biggest problem is I don't know where to format the date. I want date like a 'Y-MM-DD'. Look my code:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'Y-MM-DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'Y-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-order',
  templateUrl: './my-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-order.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})




  ngOnInit() {  
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      deliveryDate: [moment().format('Y-MM-DD')] 
   // this is return mee full ISO date like a "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z"
    });



    <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="deliveryDate"  matInput [matDatepicker]="resultOfdate" placeholder="Izaberite datum isporuke" (dateInput)="first($event.value.format('YYYY-MM-D'))"  >
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="resultOfdate" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #resultOfdate></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

I also have function which get my date look template again(above):

```
(dateInput)="first($event.value.format('YYYY-MM-D'))"
```

and when i console.log:

```
  first(e) {
    console.log("EE" , e );
    this.resultOfdate = e;
    //this is return me real date but when i pass this this.resultOfdate my control like a 

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      deliveryDate: [this.resultOfdate]
})
```

again: deliveryDate: "2019-12-21T23:00:00.000Z"

I tried everything but to no success.
I've read about some adapters that I wouldn't use if they seem more complicated to me than my current ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getDateTimeStringByUserTimeZone(moment(yourDate).format(), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
getDateTimeStringByUserTimeZone(dateTimeLocal: string, format: string): string {
       return moment.tz(dateTimeLocal, this._ianaTimeZone).format(format);
      }



Date format  can be done in ts file  if it is Datagrid column you can use pipe to cover to format
```